# Yahoo Finance API Call returning blank? Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am working on a stock watchlist project using Xamarin.Forms. To gather the stock prices before I was using IEX Cloud API, but I am attempting to use Yahoo Finance API. Im using the following code yet the `result` is returning blank.

```
namespace Stock_WatchList
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public string ApplePrice { get; set; }
        public string NioPrice { get; set; }
        public string PalantirPrice { get; set; }
        public string TeslaPrice { get; set; }
        public string XpengPrice { get; set; }
        public string AmazonPrice { get; set; }
        public string PinduoduoPrice { get; set; }
        public string DisneyPrice { get; set; }
        public string AmdPrice { get; set; }
        public string TwitterPrice { get; set; }

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            WebClient yahoo = new WebClient();
            string yahooPrices = yahoo.DownloadString("https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/chart/AAPL?interval=5m ");
            MatchCollection YahooMatches = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(yahooPrices, @"""([^""]+)"":{""quote"":{""latestPrice"":(\d+(?:.\d+))}}");
            foreach (Match match in YahooMatches)
            {
                switch (match.Groups[1].Value)
                {
                    case "regularMarketPrice":
                        ApplePrice = $"$ {match.Groups[2].Value}";
                        break;
                }
            }

            BindingContext = this;
        }

        private async void ImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new SearchPage());
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me fix this issue?

Comment: "`result` is returning blank" - I don't see `result` anywhere in your code.  Are you saying that the `yahooPrices` is null?  Or that your regex is not matching?  Why are you using regex instead of a json parser?

Comment: @Jason apologize I didn't mean to but code brackets around result, but the result in the program is just blank

Comment: You need to determine if the problem is with `yahooPrices` or `YahooMatches`.  I'd guess your regex is the problem, and that you'd get better results using a json parser.

Comment: @Jason I'm not sure how to implement a json parser, I'm somewhat new to calling data. also, I know that that link works but I don't know why it's blank

Comment: You need to figure out which is the problem.  This is basic debugging.  Put a breakpoint in the code and step through it until you find the issue.  Or just use regex tool to test your regex against the Yahoo json.  And there are **numerous** examples of parsing json in C# available on SO and all over the web.

Answer (score 0):

I called that yahoo api using Postman and received the data as json. I was able to see the data easily from that program, I agree with Jason a JSON parser would serve you better in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement that, I'm somewhat new to calling data. also, I know that that link works but I don't know why its blank

Comment: If you parse the string using a JSON parser like Newtonsoft, you will  be able to convert that string into an Object class.
Create classes first then change the call to convert the string to the class object as follows:
`string yahooPrices = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>( yahoo.DownloadString("https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/chart/AAPL?interval=5m "));
`
Use Postman to call yahoo and use that returned data to get the classes you will need for deserializing. I used https://json2csharp.com/ to convert the return json in Postman to get the required classes.